# Mapping the Php.ini Path On the Apache 2 Web Server on Mac - Phpinfo() Shows a Different Version

Tags: php, macos, apache

In my `http://localhost`, the `phpinfo()` shows a PHP 5.4.24 version with the following `php.ini` setting which does not have XDebug configuration as well:

[image: php.ini setting]

However, `php -v` command in terminal shows the following:

```
`PHP 5.6.0alpha2 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2014 07:22:12) (DEBUG)
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.6.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
   with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans`
```

How to resolve this problem that Apache server can read the configuration from the newer version with the XDebug?
Thanks

Comment: you should make sure which version is being loaded by apache. check the apache config file loading the php5_module. You will probably have to update the libphp5.so file to version php 5.6.0.

Comment: I would not alter the default install of apache on OSX.  Install a VM in virtual box or use something like MAMP.  Apple will without a whim modify stuff in /etc/ as it chooses.  I remember between panther and lion them changing the apache settings to move from /etc/http to /etc/apache2 . Doh!  That wasted about a day of my life trying troubleshoot.

Comment: @Robert, thank you for your comment. how can I update the libphp5.so? My apache config is on `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and I remember that installed the 5.6.0alpha2 version using homebrew...

Comment: @Robert, it shows the location at `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, but I can not find any `libexec` directory..

Comment: my apache libexec directory and php plugin is at: /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so  . libexec is probably an alias to /usr/libexec/apache2